# Проблема с HashMap

Tags: java

Хочу найти кол-во повторений слов в тексте. Весь тест храниться в StringBuilder sb.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // добавляем в sb текст...

    //Создаем HashMap где ключем у нас будет слово, а значением - его кол-во повторений в тексте 
    Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    //разбиваем текст на токены (слова)
    StringTokenizer wordsWithoutSymbols = new StringTokenizer(
    sb.toString(), " ,.!-+=&^%$#\"\'<>№~`_:;*?(){}\n\t");

//Пытаемся занести слова и их кол-во в HashMap (ошибка явно здесь, но не могу понять //почему оно работает неправильно)
while (wordsWithoutSymbols.hasMoreTokens()) {
    //если такой ключ уже есть в мапе - инкрементирем
    if (words.containsKey(wordsWithoutSymbols.nextToken())) {
    words.put(wordsWithoutSymbols.nextToken(),
        words.get(wordsWithoutSymbols.nextToken()) + 1);
    } else 
    words.put(wordsWithoutSymbols.nextToken(), 1);
}

    //вывод слов и кол-во их употреблений в тексте
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : words.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

В данный момент блок while отрабатывает некорректно, не могу понять почему. На выходе абсолютно не то, что ожидается. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый вызов nextToken() возвращает сдедующее слово - ключ. Соответственно проверяете вы наличие в map одного ключа, получаете и инкрементируете значение другого ключа, а результат кладете по третьему ключу.

Если же ключа в map нет, то вы его пропускаете и кладете единицу для следующего слова, при этом возможно перетирая накопленное значение.

Comment: Кошмар 0_0. А мне казалось все довольно логично. Можете объяснить, как правильно в таком случае заносить значения в повторяющиеся key?

Comment: Понял! Каждый раз при вызове nextToken() я продвигался на слово вперед. Спасибо за помощь!